# After reassigning innerHTML some features are broken

Tags: jquery, html

I need create Chrome extension that find text in html document and convert them to url using some rules.
Script works good except one issue: comment that I add in JIRA appear only after page refreshing, task 'Description' can't be modified because edit button doesn't work.

The problem is in the `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML` line

My code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: Your current code is completely wiping out the DOM and recreating it. Therefore any event handlers previously assigned will be lost. You need to either change your code to only affect the required elements, or use delegated event handlers. In this case, I would strongly suggest the former. That said, you're re-assigning the same value, so your code itself seems entirely pointless.

Comment: How I can find all elements that contain some string @RoryMcCrossan ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter along with the logic you require to search the text